Wix velo API : udatefileDescriptor method throwing 405 error
This is my page code:
 $w('#uploadMainImage').onChange(() => {

                if ($w("#uploadMainImage").value.length > 0) {
                    // $w("#text1").text = "Uploading " + $w("#uploadmainCIModelC3Button1").value[0].name;
                    $w("#uploadMainImage")                        
                        .uploadFiles()
                        .then(async (uploadedFiles) => {
                            // $w("#text1").text = "Upload successful";
                            $w("#mainCapsuleImage").src = uploadedFiles[0].fileUrl;
                            const filename = uploadedFiles[0].fileName
                            imageID = uploadedFiles[0].fileName
                            console.log("filename: " + " " + filename);
                            console.log(uploadedFiles[0].fileUrl)
                            console.log("filename: " + " " + uploadedFiles[0].originalFileName)
                            currentDisplayName = uploadedFiles[0].originalFileName
                        })
                        .catch((uploadError) => {
                            // $w("#text1").text = "File upload error";
                            console.log("File upload error: " + uploadError.errorCode);
                            console.log(uploadError.errorDescription);
                        });
                } else {
                    // $w("#text1").text = "Please choose a file to upload.";
                }

            })
            console.log("1" + " " + imageID + ' ' + '2' + " " + currentDisplayName)
            $w('#change').onClick(async () => {
                console.log("1" + " " + imageID + ' ' + '2' + " " + currentDisplayName)

                let fileDesc = await myGetFileDescriptorFunction(imageID)
                console.log("file desc: " + fileDesc);

                const imageId = fileDesc._id;
                const fileUpdates = {
                    displayName: "Space-Capsules-testname.jpg",
                    fieldMask: [fileDesc.displayName]

                };

                const updatedLocation = await updateFile(imageId, fileUpdates);
                // console.log(
                //     "Display name successfully updated to:",
                //     updatedLocation.displayName,
                // );
            })

This is my backend code:
import { Permissions, webMethod } from "wix-web-module";
import { files } from "wix-media.v2";
import { elevate } from "wix-auth";


export const updateFile = webMethod(
  Permissions.Anyone,
  async (fileId, file) => {
    console.log ("fileIDDD: " + fileId + "  " + " FileInfo:   " + file)
    try {
      const elevatedUpdateFileDescriptor = elevate(files.updateFileDescriptor);
      const updatedDescriptor = await elevatedUpdateFileDescriptor(
        fileId,
        file,
      );

      return updatedDescriptor;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
);

export const listImages = webMethod(Permissions.Anyone, async () => {
  const listOptions = {
    mediaTypes: [],
  };

  try {
    const elevatedListFiles = elevate(files.listFiles);
    const images = await elevatedListFiles(listOptions);

    return images.files;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

export const myGetFileDescriptorFunction = webMethod(
  Permissions.Anyone,
  async (fileId) => {
    try {
      const elevatedGetFileDescriptor = elevate(files.getFileDescriptor);
      const descriptor = await elevatedGetFileDescriptor(fileId);

      console.log("Retrieved descriptor:", descriptor);
      return descriptor;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // Handle the error
    }
  },
);

I was expecting it to update the file displayName for the specified file ID on clickining Change button., but it is throwing 405 error
here it is:
message: 'INTERNAL: Unexpected error: Request failed with status code 405: The method is not allowed for the requested URL.'
details:
applicationError:
description: The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
code: GENERAL_API_ERROR
data:
internalCode: '405'
internalHttpStatusCode: 405
console log image
